# OWL; checking that a generalization is full

Tags: owl, ontology

Let's consider a simple ontology consisting of a base class (animal) and two subclasses (dog, cat). 
Is there anyway on the schema level (not the data level) to ensure that each individual of class (animal) is either a dog or a cat.
What I mean is how to check that each individual of a class always is an individual of a subclasses (any subclass, no matter which). That's on the ontology schema level, not the data level?
In other words, in UML generalizations we have total and partial ones; thus I want to ensure that my generalization in ontology is total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, all you need to do is say that every animal is either a dog or a cat.  In this case, since dog and cat are both subclasses of animal, you could simply say:

> Animal ≡ (Dog ⊔ Cat)

> Animal EquivalentClass (Dog or Cat)

This means that if something is an Animal, then it is also a (Dog or Cat).  If something is a (Dog or Cat), then it must either be a Dog or be a Cat.

More generally, if you just want to say that every X is either a Y or a Z, but you still want to allow the possibility of a Y or Z that isn't necessarily an X (this is in contrast to your question, since every Cat and every Dog is also an Animal), you can simply say that X is a *subclass* of (Y or Z).  That is:

> X ⊑ (Y ⊔ Z)

> X SubClassOf  (Y or Z)

Comment: Well; That's great. But let's just generalize my question and say: If have a given ontology O; Containing classes X (super) and Y, Z (sub); how do I check that each Y or Z is X on the schema level; i.e. what are all the possible situations? Is checking the two situations you have introduced (⊔, EquivalentClass) is enough or there are additional scenarios that enforces what I want. Then what are them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking in the comment.  If you want to say that every Y and every Z is an X, all you need to do is say that Y is a subclass of X and that Z is a subclass of X.  You could do that with two axioms (Y subClassOf X), (Z subClassOf X), or you could do it with one ((Y or Z) subClassOf X).

Comment: No, Actually that's not what I mean. I mean that I have a given ontology O; Containing classes X (super class) and Y, Z (subclasses of X); and I want to CHECK if "each X is either Y or Z"; not ENFORCE it. Then (what I think) I have to search in Ontology axioms for axioms providing this information ("each X is either Y or Z"). Then what are the possible axioms to search for beside the two you introduced in you reply? Thanks

Comment: @MedianHilal OK, well, that's what it sounded like when you asked "how do I check that each Y or Z is X on the schema level?"  Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I mean that axioms you have given (Animal ≡ (Dog ⊔ Cat), Animal EquivalentClass (Dog or Cat)) helps to ENFORCE that each animal is either a cat or a dog. I don't want to ENFORCE that. I want to CHECK if it's true on the schema level i.e. without the need to reason about individuals in the ontology. I hope this makes it clear

Comment: OK, if you just want to check (based on the class axioms), you can just use a reasoner and *ask* whether "X subClassOf (Y or Z)".  If it is, then every X would have to be a Y or Z.  Note that if you don't reason about individuals, you might not get completely accurate results.

Comment: OK. Thanks I got it. But one last point please. Can you just tell me what are all the possible axioms that tell "X would have to be a Y or Z" ?

Comment: In general, I don't think that you'll be able to do that. After all, there can be lots of complex interactions between axioms.  As a not too complicated example, if you had `D subClassOf (p some Thing)` and `p rdfs:domain C`, then it would be the case that D is a subclass of C.  To decide subsumption, you really want to use an automated reasoner.

Comment: What I would do for that is checking that Animal disjointUnionOf Cat and Dog is entailed (disjoint union is shorthand for the same axioms described above: an animal is a cat or a dog, no cat is a dog, and no animal is not a cat and not a dog